# Google Calendar Insert Events not executing

Tags: android, kotlin, google-calendar-api

I have the following Kotlin code in my Android app:

```
    fun scheduleMeeting(start: Date, end: Date, prospect: 
Prospect, callback: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
        doAsync {
            var event = createMeeting(start, end, prospect)
            event = service.events().insert("primary", event)
                    .setSendNotifications(true)
                    .execute()
            lastEventAdded = GIDEvent(event)
            syncCalendars()
            syncCalendarsAsync()
            uiThread {
                CommonAlerts.calAlert(lastEventAdded!!, 
prospect.name!!)
                callback(true)
            }
        }
    }
```

Expected Behavior: Add the event to user calendar and alert the user of success.

Current Behavior: code does not execute beyond service.events().insert()

This was working and then one day it suddenly it stopped working. I cannot find any errors in logcat or anything to tell me what is wrong

Comment: This question is very concise and well structured. Have you update your developer environment or gradle version? Or are you testing on a different Android version?

Comment: Thanks! It turned out that indeed nothing was wrong with this particular function.

I just spent the entire day debugging and finally traced it back to events being created that had end dates in the past. I added some logic to keep it from happening and now it seems to be functioning correctly.